# Get rest of file path as string after third occurrence of folder name search

Tags: java, string, substring

For example if I want the name of a file and I have a string:

```
string = "C:\MyFiles\User\admin\local\toCopy\local\recentFiles\local\textFile\textFile.txt

containerName = "local";
function find fileName( string containerName, string path ){

...
}
```

Should return: `textFile textFile.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String findFileName(String containerName, String path){
    int counter=0;
    String [] sa = path.split("\\\\");
    String res="";

    for(int i=0; i<sa.length; i++)
    {

        if(counter==3)
           res+=sa[i]+" ";
        if(sa[i].equals(containerName))
            counter++;
        if(counter==3)
           res+=sa[i]+" ";
    }

    return res.trim();
}
```

note that `\` needs escaping. so the above should be called as

`findFileName("local","C:\\MyFiles\\User\\admin\\local\\toCopy\\local\\recentFiles\\local\\textFile\\textFile.txt")`

and it returns

`textFile textFile.txt`